# How to use Windows Azure toolkit (iOS) for MAC OS Lion?

Tags: azure

Today, that's great when Microsoft provide Windows Azure toolkit for iOS, but I want to use this toolkit to build app runs on Mac OS, I've tried many ways to integrate and failed. So anybody knows this problem? please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After few days research, I know how to use this library in iOS, put the needed files into Mac OS application to implement this library but until now, I cannot implement it succeed. I will back with the right answer.